# Why would a faction betray its leader in the middle of war?

Tags: medieval, politics, history

Basically my protagonist is a medieval princess who refuses to marry either warring claimants to her throne.

Eliminate one claimant, and his faction would naturally defect to the other claimant. Of course the princess’s own faction are just as self-serving—they would collude to win the favor of the surviving claimant by having her marry him. If she refuses, then she would viewed as refusing the easiest and most obvious path to peace, a capricious woman unworthy of the throne.

Therefore she has to eliminate both claimants at roughly around the same time. One will be in battle, and the other due to his allies having turned against him.

What are historical examples wherein a faction suddenly betrayed its leader during an ongoing conflict with another faction (or maybe two factions)?

Comment: (1) If she is on the throne, there cannot be any legimitate claimants to the throne. Those claimants are traitors to the crown. (2) It is not in any way "natural" for a faction to join another faction when its leader dies. (3) If her own faction is self-serving then she is a bad regnant princess and she deserves all she gets. (3) There are *numerous* historical example of leaders being betrayed by their men. As in, you will find them wherever you look. Have you heard of a certain Judas of Kerioth? Two directly pertinent examples are Napoleon at Leipzig and Andriscus of Macedon at Pydna.

Comment: As for *"why would a faction betray its leader in the middle of war"*, the usual reasons are (1) money or wealth in general, (2) pride, (3) ideology, (4) religion, (5) blackmail, (6) awakened patriotism, (7) injured honor, (8) survival instinct, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

#### Example: [Neville Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville_Chamberlain#War_leader_(1939%E2%80%931940))

Basically because he wasn't doing that great a job in the war. In 6 months of "fighting" European countries had been falling rapidly, and the loss of Norway was the final straw for his allies in parliament. He survived an attempt on him by his allies turning against him.

120 allies turned against his leadership (From the wikipedia link):

> When the division took place, the government, which had a normal majority of over 200, prevailed by only 81, with 38 MPs in receipt of the government whip voting against it, with between 20 and 25 abstaining.

When Hitler invaded the low countries (Ie Belgium, Netherlands and Luxembourg), his former allies turned against him (Labor party were no longer supporting his government), he resigned, making way for Churchill, and the rest is history...

Comment: Yes, but he was replaced by another, more belligerent member of his faction.  The question is how does the princess get them to transfer their allegiance to her.